# Bluetooth disappeared in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a Lenovo G580 laptop. In the past, using Windows 8, I could use Bluetooth to connect to other devices.

Installing Windows 10, Bluetooth simply disappeared. I can't find anything related to Bluetooth in the Device Manager, also in *Settings* → *Devices*.

There is no Windows 10 Bluetooth driver for my laptop.

What can I do?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. How did you finally solved it?

Comment: Any update here? @SayanPal same, did you end up finding a fix? This is exactly my issue as well (different device).

Comment: @Gryph updating the BIOS actually fixed it for me.

Comment: @SayanPal Thanks. I actually just tried updating my BIOS based on this working for you - I did get BT back in the device manager, but not in settings. I expect I've got a hardware failure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not due to drivers, fast boot or USB problems. In fact, it's simpler than it looks.

I ran to the same problem 4 days ago. After researching for 4 days, I finally found the solution. You don't have to update Windows or install fresh one.

The problem is the BIOS settings. Just find the latest drivers for the BIOS of your motherboard from the manufacturer's site and install it. That's all.

If you don't know how to update BIOS drivers, you can follow the following steps.

- Download the required drivers from the website of your motherboard's manufacturer.
- Extract the zipped file with any unzipping software (I recommend 7z). Copy that file to any USB flash drive/pen drive.
- Restart your system and go to the BIOS settings by pressing the "x" button on the startup screen. "x" is different for different models. For me it was <kbd>F2</kbd> as I have an Asus Vivobook X-series. Every laptop's manufacturer defines its own key to change the BIOS settings.
- After that, update the BIOS using the USB drive. Usually, the BIOS update option is in the advanced tab, but just like "x", every BIOS is different. You have to find the suitable menu option to update the BIOS for your system.
- Initiate the update process. It will take some time. After that, restart your system, and you are done.

You will be able to find the  missing Bluetooth option in the device manager. And your USB issue should be solved automatically after updating the BIOS. Only update if if your problem isn't solved.

[This article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-update-bios-on-windows) shows other ways to update the BIOS:

Answer (score 0):

The problem just comes from the fact the manufacturer hasn't provided a Windows 10 driver yet, at least from Windows Update.

Here is how to try and fix the problem:

1. Open your Device Manager: your Bluetooth device should logically show with a yellow exclamation mark indicating a missing driver.

   Well, this is not exactly a step. It's only to check if your device is actually detected... :p
2. Since the driver isn't available (yet) from Windows Update, go to Levovo's drivers download section and find your laptop.
3. If there's an available Windows 10 driver, download and install it.
4. If not, then search for a Windows 8.1 driver (that should exist).

   Once downloaded, right click on the setup program and select "Properties". In the "Compatibility" tab, check the "run this program in compatibility mode for" box, then select "Windows 8" in the drop down menu below. Click "OK" then run the program.

   Windows 10 and 8.1 drivers architectures are very close, if not completely identical most of the time. It should work OK.

#### Important note

Most laptops have a way to disable Bluetooth to save the battery.

This actually hides the hardware from Windows, making it disappear from the Device Manager, so if you can't find it there, then you've probably accidentally hit the function key that toggles it on or off.

Check on your keyboard top raw for a Bluetooth logo and hit the key while the Device Manager is displayed: if it's the case, then you should see it coming back. You may need to hold the blue "Fn" key to access this function, depending on whether you've turned the classical function keys on or not from the BIOS.

I've searched the Lenovo drivers section, and no driver is currently available for Windows 10, explaining why it has been removed (it's not available either from Windows Update, of course).

However, you'll find one for Windows 8.1 that should be compatible if you install it the way I explained above (pick the one matching your hardware variant):

Broadcom:

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/Lenovo-G-Series-laptops/Lenovo-G580-Notebook/downloads/DS037359

LiteOn:

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/Lenovo-G-Series-laptops/Lenovo-G580-Notebook/downloads/DS037674