# Bluetooth disappeared from the device manager after clean installation of windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

Yesterday, I reformatted my Lenovo G580 laptop, and ran a clean installation of Windows 10. After the installation Bluetooth disappeared completely. I waited till all the updates are downloaded and installed. However, this did not install the bluetooth driver. Note that before this clean installation, I was running Windows 10 with Bluetooth perfectly working.

The Bluetooth disappeared from Device Manager. There is no entry containing Bluetooth in name, including the hidden devices. I tried to install the drivers from [Lenovo's support website](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g580-notebook/downloads?linkTrack=Caps%3ABody_SearchProduct&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=G580%20Laptop%20(Lenovo)). As there are nothing available for Windows 10, I tried to install the ones for Windows 8.1, [with compatibility mode set to Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/1070940/bluetooth-disappeared-in-windows-10). But none of those drivers were installed due to the following compatibility issue.

> Realtek Bluetooth suite can't run on Windows

I also tried correcting the [Bluetooth Support Service](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/bluetooth-not-showing-in-device-manager-fixed/), but nothing changed. I tried to troubleshoot Bluetooth as per [Microsoft's official help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14169/windows-10-fix-bluetooth-problems) on this. The troubleshooter said that

> Device does not have bluetooth
>
> Bluetooth is not available on this device. Please try using an external adapter to add Bluetooth capability to this computer

Being clueless now, I tried to reset the BIOS to its default settings, as some of the internet articles and/or SE sites suggested. I have already seen this [Option to Turn Bluetooth on or off is Missing](https://superuser.com/questions/946581/option-to-turn-bluetooth-on-or-off-is-missing) and tried some of the suggested solutions. But nothing worked.

Please advise on how to solve this problem?

**Additional details:** I tried Ubuntu with a bootable USB, and bluetooth worked there like charm. However, when I logged back into Windows, it was still the same (no bluetooth).

**Solution worked on my machine:** I finally solved it by updating BIOS from [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/LENOVO-G-SERIES-LAPTOPS/LENOVO-G580-NOTEBOOK/downloads/DS039067). I rebooted after installation, and the bluetooth is there in the device manager :)

Comment: Looking at Lenovo page there is plenty of drivers there, which one did you tried? You need to install the one corresponding to your manufacturer Bluetooth chip.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I tried this one "Bluetooth Driver (Broadcom, Atheros)File Name: bt200w81.exe OS: Windows 8.1 32-bit, 64-bitVersion: 12.0.0.7620 (BTW 12.0.0.7800) / 8.0.1.300"

Comment: In Device Manager (with hidden devices shown), expand `Universal Serial Bus Controllers`. Select `USB Root Hub`, then switch the view to `Devices by connection`. Are there any unknown devices showing?

Comment: @KeithMiller I tried that. There was an "unknown usb device (device descriptor request failed)". Uninstalled the device with the hope that the driver will be correctly installed on restart. That did not happen, and the device is now gone for good :(

Answer (score 1):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-disappered-from-device-manager-with/fd246f79-c31c-40a2-a0a1-5660e0e07cfc

Check out the post by digitiser.

The summary is:

- Turn off computer
- Unplug power
- Hold power button for 90 seconds
- Plug in
- Boot

The idea here is the motherboard doesn't see the bluetooth chip and by holding the power button you are draining the capacitors and allowing the chip to reestablish a connection.

Comment: For some reason this was the only things that worked

Answer (score 0):

Longer method is to

use linuxmint/any linux with liveiso on USB (rufus is DD mode) boot from it.

once reached desktop run level run the commands

lsusb

lspci

capture all as text and look for text with bluetooth

usually lenovo has Atheros/Broadcomm for wifi/bluetooth

OR

shorter method try using DriverBooster/IOBIT

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, none of these 2 work. I tried Ubuntu from a bootable USB. Bluetooth worked there, but it disappeared when I logged back in to Windows. And DriverBooster does not acknowledge existence of any Bluetooth device on machine. Therefore, there is no question of updating the driver.

Comment: have you found out which was the bluetooth module from Linux ?

Comment: It is Broadcom BCM20702

Comment: https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/downloads/ds031999, can you check if this helps ?

Comment: Nope, does not work. It cannot detect the bluetooth device :(

Comment: Finally solved it by updating BIOS. Thank you for your help anyway :)